# What event is called when a .ascx control is set to visible? How can it be handled?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, .net-2.0

If I set a .ascx control's visible attribute to true, what event is called?  What method can I create in that control's codebehind to act on this event?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No event is raised. But you can add a handler for the PreRender event and check there whether the control's Visible property is set to True or False.

Comment: Excellent, thanks a lot.  I'm assuming PreRender is called every time the page renders anything, not just on post back?

Comment: You would have to post back to set the ascx property to visible so I'm not sure it matters.